# git diffs between current branch and parent branch

Tags: git, github

I have cloned https://github.com/hardkernel/linux/tree/odroid-3.8.y, and would like to find the diffs between this and the last merge point ('v3.8.13.16' of git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/linux)

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: `git diff master refs/tags/v3.8.13.16`?

Comment: `> git diff master refs/tags/v3.8.16.13
    fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Comment: In that case, try `refs/heads/master` or `refs/remotes/origin/master` instead of `master`...

Comment: hmm. i gave up on it. thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repo https://github.com/hardkernel/linux/tree/odroid-3.8.y **has no master branch**.

So you need a:

```
git diff refs/tags/v3.8.13.16
```

In order to compare that older tag with your current HEAD.

But that will only work if you did import tags from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git-repos/ubuntu/linux.git/

```
git remote add ubuntu http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git-repos/ubuntu/linux.git
git fetch --tags ubuntu
```

However, as described in "[On the Perils of Importing Remote Tags in Git](http://www.pythian.com/blog/on-the-perils-of-importing-remote-tags-in-git/)", that would clobber your own tags: in case of a remote tag named like a local tag, a  `git fetch --tags` would **overwrite** the SHA1 referenced by your local tag by the SHA1 referenced by the remote tag you just fetched.

So it is best to use `git ls-remote --tags` to get the right SHA1 without importing *all* the tags (I mean 898 of them) of the `kernel.ubuntu.com/git-repos/ubuntu/linux` repo.

```
git ls-remote --tags http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git-repos/ubuntu/linux.git|grep 3.8.13.16

git diff a8cfe8030
```